# Add formula with nodejs google sheet

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm able to add values in a raw with node.js library (official google)
But I don't understand How can I insert formula in a cell

```
const append = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: "xxx",
            range: 'my',
            insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
            valueInputOption: 'RAW',
            resource: {
            values: [
                ['',moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY"), "s", "0.0000010","0.0000009",'x','x','x','x','',"","0.0000013"]
                ],
        },
```

with this snippet I can append the values at my sheet. Where I put X I'd like to insert a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, please use `USER_ENTERED` instead of `RAW`.

#### Modified script:

```
const append = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: "xxx",
            range: 'my',
            insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
            valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',  // Modified
            resource: {
            values: [
                ['',moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY"), "s", "0.0000010","0.0000009",'=NOW()','=NOW()','=NOW()','=NOW()','',"","0.0000013"] // Modified
                ],
        },
```

- In this modification, as a sample, `=NOW()` is put to the cells.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)